# Particular integral in complementary function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]
Why does multiplying by $x$ work here? Is this a general rule when the particular integral in complementary function

Comment: If I have $y_c = xf(x)$ then $y_c' = f(x) + xf'(x)$ etc so if $f$ was a solution of the homogeneous equation the $x$ terms will cancel out leaving behind only the inhomogenous term. The deeper reason has to do with a concept in linear algebra called a generalized eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

$$y''-5y'+6y=e^{2x}$$
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$r^2-5r+6 =0 \implies (r-2)(r-3)=0$$
$$ \implies S_r= \{2,3\}$$
The solution of the homogeneous equation is :
$$y(x)=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{3x}$$
So the particular solution should be 
$$y_p(x)=Axe^{2x}$$
Normally the guess should be $Ae^{2x}$. But since $e^{2x}$ is already solution of the homogeneous equation, you need to multiply by $x$ the guess.

---

**EDIT**

A good exercice is to solve the following equation :
$$y''-4y'+4y=e^{2x}$$
Try it ..

Comment: Multiply by x as a rule of thumb, or in any case?

Comment: Multiply by x. if $e^{2x}$ is a solution of mutliplicity 1 and multiply by $x^2$ if you had a characteristic polynomial like $(r-2)^2=0$ So it depends on the multiplicity of the root of the characteristic polynomial  @jamie

Comment: @jamie Try to solve the equation I proposed in the edit of my answer.

Comment: So I solved the characteristic equation and got repeated roots. so $Axe^{2x}+Be^{2x}$. Since the x term was also already present, I used $x^2e^{2x}$ as the particular integral and worked out. I'm fine with this as a method, but it doesn't really make intuitive sense to me. Why does multiplying by $x$ help? Because its the only way to get the $e^{2x}$ term alone in the product rule?

Comment: Thats perfect...@jamie Once you have a solution of the differential equation you can always use the method of reduction of order to find the othe solution...You will get that extra x times the solution as second solution.

Answer (score 0):

The intrinsic structure of this phenomenon can be seen via the operator viewpoint:

If ${D_x}^2(y) - 5·D_x(y) + 6 y = e^{2x}$ then:

$( {D_x}^2 - 5·D_x + 6 )(y) = e^{2x}$.

$(D_x-2)( {D_x}^2 - 5·D_x + 6 )(y) = (D_x-2)(e^{2x})$.

$(D_x-2)(D_x-2)(D_x-3)(y) = 0$.

It should be clear that the extra polynomial factor arises from the multiplicity of $(D_x-2)$.

Of course, there are other details to fill in, but the intrinsic structure is here. An exactly analogous phenomenon happens with the forward difference operator for the same reason.

Comment: My answer assumes that you know the full proof of the general solution of homogenous linear ODE. If you do not, then it is best to learn that first, so that you understand where this polynomial factor comes from.